# Session [url] not available and is not among the last 1000 terminated sessions. How to solve this?

Tags: php, session, selenium, selenium-webdriver, behat

When I try to launch

> php behat.phar

The WebDriver firefox window pops up and then my feature test fails at first step and skips the rest. I get:

> ...
>
> Given I am on "first.php" #FeatureContext::visit()
>
> Session [url] not available and is not among the last 1000 terminated sessions.
>
> Active sessions are[ext. key 51191ae0-8f6f-49d0-27b322967296]
>
> ...

If I only use behat the test passes. This happens only when I try to use selenium.

I'm using MinkExtension GivenIAmOn() premade function

my behat.yml:

```
default:
    paths:
        features: features
        bootstrap: features/bootstrap
    extensions:
        mink_extension.phar:
            mink_loader: 'mink.phar'
            base_url: 'http://10.0.0.10/'
            goutte: ~
            selenium2:
                wd_host: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'
                capabilities:
                    version: ''
```

My FeatureContext extends from MinkContext.
I've been searching for a solution for days and I couldn't solve this.

I'm working with Windows 7 with firefox 26, selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2 and I tried lower versions as well. As I read in some issues, the session/"session-id"/url was broken some versions ago, but now it shouldn't. For some reason it can't pick the right session.

Sorry for the data quality, I don't have an internet connection at my workplace and it's quite restricted. That's why I use .phar files instead of using composer. I can't either copy-paste the files and so on. If I have to provide more data just tell me and I will.

Comment: I solved it, but I still don't know what was wrong. I installed behat and mink through composer when I got the chance to do it and now it's working. Maybe any of the .phar files were corrupted!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a [grid-level](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2) timeout issue. You should try to increase `browserTimeout` and `newSessionWaitTimeout` and see if that helps.

Source: [Session not available and is not among the last 1000 terminated sessions](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/7677).

> Timeouts in the grid should normally be handled through `webDriver.manage().timeouts()`, which will control how the different operations time out.

The browserTimeout should be:

- Higher than the socket lock timeout (45 seconds).
- Generally higher than values used in `webDriver.manage().timeouts()`, since this mechanism is a "last line of defense".

For any issues, check also: http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/sessions

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and logs of Selenium Grid are this :

> WARN [RequestHandler.process] - **The client is gone** for session ext. key fa804448787370d0547cd517ab2badc1, terminating
>   INFO [ActiveTestSessions.updateReason] - Removed a session that had not yet assigned an external key 24f5656a-7a59-4edb-bf7b-c6a1ae59ca16, indicates failure in session **creation CLIENT_GONE**

The error `CLIENT_GONE` is :

> "The client process (your code) appears to have died or otherwise not responded to our requests, intermittent network issues may also cause".

And I had some test that are waiting in queue (5 tests are waiting, while 5 other are running)

I solve this problem with just stoping to have queue on grid.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by using the same version of the selenium hub and the nodes:
image: selenium/hub:3.11
AND
image: selenium/node-chrome:3.11