# Behat with selenium 2 fail to connect to localhost

Tags: php, symfony, selenium, behat

Im trying to setup my behat tests in selenium enviroment. For now i got selenium starting with dockers,

Thats my docker-compose.yml config:

```
hub:
  image: selenium/hub
  ports:
    - "4444:4444"

chrome:
  image: selenium/node-chrome
  links:
    - hub
```

And i got my behat.yml configurated:

```
default:
    suites:
        default:
            paths:
                features: 'tests/features'
                bootstrap:  'tests/features/bootstrap'
            contexts:
                - FeatureContext: ~
    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension: ~
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            base_url:  http://localhost
            selenium2: ~
```

And when i launch my tests with @javascript (i suppose this launch selenium env) i get error:

> Could not open connection: Curl error thrown for http POST to http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session with params: {"desiredCapabilities":{"tags":["cli","PHP 7.0.15-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1"],"browser":"firefox","ignoreZoomSetting":false,"name":"Behat feature suite","browserName":"firefox"}}
>
> Failed to connect to localhost port 4444: Connection refused (Behat\Mink\Exception\DriverException)

When I get on http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/sessions i get:

> {"status":13,"value":{"message":"Session [(null externalkey)] not available and is not among the last 1000 terminated sessions.\nActive sessions are[]","class":"org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException","stackTrace":[{"fileName":"ActiveTestSessions.java","className":"org.openqa.grid.internal.ActiveTestSessions","methodName":"getExistingSession","lineNumber":110},{"fileName":"Registry.java","className":"org.openqa.grid.internal.Registry","methodName":"getExistingSession","lineNumber":404},{"fileName":"RequestHandler.java","className":"org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler","methodName":"getSession","lineNumber":232},{"fileName":"RequestHandler.java","className":"org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler","methodName":"process","lineNumber":117},{"fileName":"DriverServlet.java","className":"org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet","methodName":"process","lineNumber":83},{"fileName":"DriverServlet.java","className":"org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet","methodName":"doGet","lineNumber":61},{"fileName":"HttpServlet.java","className":"javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet","methodName":"service","lineNumber":687},{"fileName":"HttpServlet.java","className":"javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet","methodName":"service","lineNumber":790},{"fileName":"ServletHolder.java","className":"org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder","methodName":"handle","lineNumber":808},{"fileName":"ServletHandler.java","className":"org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler","methodName":"doHandle","lineNumber":587},{"fileName":"SessionHandler.java","className":"org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler","methodName":"doHandle","lineNumber":221},{"fileName":"ContextHandler.java","className":"org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler","methodName":"doHandle","lineNumber":1127},{"fileName":"ServletHandler.java","className":"org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler","methodName":"doScope","lineNumber":515},{"fileName":"SessionHandler.java","className":"org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler","methodName":"doScope","lineNumber":185},{"fileName":"ContextHandler.java","className":"org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler","methodName":"doScope","lineNumber":1061},{"fileName":"ScopedHandler.java","className":"org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler","methodName":"handle","lineNumber":141},{"fileName":"HandlerWrapper.java","className":"org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper","methodName":"handle","lineNumber":97},{"fileName":"Server.java","className":"org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server","methodName":"handle","lineNumber":499},{"fileName":"HttpChannel.java","className":"org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel","methodName":"handle","lineNumber":310},{"fileName":"HttpConnection.java","className":"org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection","methodName":"onFillable","lineNumber":257},{"fileName":"AbstractConnection.java","className":"org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$2","methodName":"run","lineNumber":540},{"fileName":"QueuedThreadPool.java","className":"org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool","methodName":"runJob","lineNumber":635},{"fileName":"QueuedThreadPool.java","className":"org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3","methodName":"run","lineNumber":555},{"fileName":"Thread.java","className":"java.lang.Thread","methodName":"run","lineNumber":745}]}}

I suppose its a problem with configuration of behat, but im not sure, since im just started using behat and selenium. If someone got any idea what is wrong i would be very pleased to get some help.

Comment: Related: [Session not available and is not among the last 1000 terminated sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24446745/55075)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `wd_host` and `capabilities` options

try something like:

```
default:
    suites:
        default:
            paths:
                features: 'tests/features'
                bootstrap:  'tests/features/bootstrap'
            contexts:
                - FeatureContext: ~
    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension: ~
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            selenium2:
                browser: "chrome"
                wd_host: http://hub:4444/wd/hub
```

Also your hub, needs to be able to access your localhost.....where the tests are running.

First, try to checkout your apache/nginx etc of your server, to see if you are getting any access/visits from the selenium machine.

something like `tail -f /var/log/apache/access.log`

or wherever you are saving your files....if you get nothing, then obviously selenium is not accessing your machine

A different approach would be, to deploy your code for example of a test env, then you can do something in your `behat.yml` like:

```
    Behat\MinkExtension:
        base_url:  http://my_test_host.com
```

Comment: Well, I used first approach. Seems like it worked. But still not enough, now im getting error:

`Could not open connection: Error forwarding the new session Empty pool of VM for setup Capabilities [{browser=firefox, name=Behat feature suite, browserName=chrome, ignoreZoomSetting=false, tags=[cli, PHP 7.0.15-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1]}] (Behat\Mink\Exception\DriverException)`

Comment: I edited my post...do you get any hits from selenium on your server? otherwise try to edit value of `base_url` in `behat.yml` to `base_url:  http://whtaeverr_your_php_container_is_called_indocker_compose`

Comment: I checked logs, and it seems like my tests doesnt even hits selenium. I added `base_url: http://localhost` to my `behat.yml`. But still got same error.