# WebDriverException: Session not available and is not among the last 1000 terminated sessions with GeckoDriver and Firefox in SeleniumGrid

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-grid, geckodriver

#### Problem

When I execute 2 nodes of Firefox  with 1 instance each no problem. But if I execute with 3 or more than 3 nodes getting the below error. No Problem if I execute 100 Test cases in chrome but seems Firefox not able to handle so many test cases. I have high config server with 64 GB RAM. I also observed, with 3 nodes the consumption of memory is never goes beyond 70%

#### HUB

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -role hub -browserTimeout 30 -timeout 90
```

#### Node

```
java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=./geckodriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -role node  -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=firefox, -port 7771
```

#### Code Snap-1

```
private WebDriver firefoxDriver() {
WebDriver driver;
driver = null;
try{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",Constants.sFirefoxDriverPath);

    FirefoxOptions opt= new FirefoxOptions();
    opt.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
    opt.setCapability("marionette", true);          
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(Constants.sHubUrl), opt);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}catch(Exception ex){           
    logger.error("Error in Firefox Driver --> " , ex);
    driver.close();
}
return driver;
```

}

#### Code Snap -2

```
private WebDriver firefoxDriver() {
WebDriver driver;
driver = null;
try{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",Constants.sFirefoxDriverPath);
    DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    cap.setCapability("marionette",true);
    cap.setVersion("ANY");
    cap.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(Constants.sHubUrl), cap);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}catch(Exception ex){           
    logger.error("Error in Firefox Driver --> " , ex);
    driver.close();
}
return driver;
```

}

#### Error Message

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Session [4c40e39b-ac68-459a-ac33-f77d5f7d57f8] not available and is not among the last 1000 terminated sessions.
Active sessions are[ext. key 6ee03f37-a595-4d82-a0e3-2aed3ff42df5, ext. key 6db69284-3582-4c6a-950b-7ca4e0bbc059, ext. key 5d3d5a41-101e-4bfc-858a-b20ae0e916fb]
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'XXXXXX', ip: 'XXX.XX.XXX.XXX', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_192'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 63.0.1, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.23.0, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 14432, moz:profile: C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\..., moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, platformVersion: 6.3, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webdriver.remote.sessionid: 4c40e39b-ac68-459a-ac33-f77...}
Session ID: 4c40e39b-ac68-459a-ac33-f77d5f7d57f8
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions$RemoteTimeouts.implicitlyWait(RemoteWebDriver.java:776)
    at com.HCF_AutomationFramework_Selenium.keyWords.kDrivers.firefoxDriver(kDrivers.java:134)
    at com.HCF_AutomationFramework_Selenium.keyWords.kDrivers.kSelectDriver(kDrivers.java:42)
    at com.Modules.EmailQuote.TestCases.EmailQuote.EmailQuote_Referer_CustomiseCover(EmailQuote.java:93)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:643)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods (TestMethodWorker.java:129)    
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some more information about your *usecase* might have helped us to analyze the issue in a better way. However, you need to take care a couple of facts as follows:

- Initiating the *Selenium Grid Hub* with the following configuration seems insufficient:

  `-browserTimeout 30 -timeout 90`
- You may consider setting them to the default value os follows:

  `-browserTimeout 0 -timeout 1800`
- While initiating the *Selenium Grid Node* you need to provide the *absolute path* of the **GeckoDriver** as follows:

  ```
  java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=./geckodriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -role node  -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=firefox, -port 7771
  ```
- You may consider setting them to the default value as follows:

  ```
  java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=C:/path/to/geckodriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -role node -port 7771 -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=firefox, maxInstances=5, seleniumProtocol=WebDriver"
  ```

---

### Additional Consideration

As per the following discussions:

- [Session [url] not available and is not among the last 1000 terminated sessions. How to solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24446745/session-url-not-available-and-is-not-among-the-last-1000-terminated-sessions)
- [Selenium: Session externalKey not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53904809/selenium-session-externalkey-not-available)

It seems this error occurs when:

- *Selenium Grid Hub*, *Selenium Grid Node* and the *Client Process* are initiated/spawned from **different versions** of *Selenium* client.

---

### Solution

Ensure that *Selenium Grid Hub*, *Selenium Grid Node* and the *Client Process* all of them uses the same version of *Selenium* client i.e. **Selenium v3.141.59**

Comment: Interestingly enough, I don't get this error when my hub is on standalone v3.0.1 and the node is on 3.141.59, but if I update it for the hub and node to both use 3.141.59, that CAUSES this error.